# How to iterate component in loop?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that contains a few components:

```
<app-comp1 *ngIf="current == '1'"></app-comp1>
<app-comp2 *ngIf="current == '2'></app-comp2>
<app-comp3 *ngIf="current == '3'></app-comp3>
<app-comp_N *ngIf="current == 'N'></app-comp_N>
```

Is it possible to define these components in parent component like this:

```
public childComponents: [AppComp1, AppComp2, AppComp3, ...N];
```

Then iterate them in template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let component of childComponents">
   {{ component }}
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Dynamic components:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component

```html
   <ng-container *ngFor="let component of childComponents">
    <ndc-dynamic
      [ndcDynamicComponent]="component"
    ></ndc-dynamic>
   </ng-container>
```

Also you should look at the documentation to provice input and output data, since dynamic components, can't be easily bind to values.

Dynamic Component with Input and Output params:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <ndc-dynamic
      [ndcDynamicComponent]="component"
      [ndcDynamicInputs]="inputs"
      [ndcDynamicOutputs]="outputs"
    ></ndc-dynamic>
  `,
})
class MyComponent {
  component = MyDynamicComponent1;
  inputs = {
    hello: 'world',
    something: () => 'can be really complex',
  };
  outputs = {
    onSomething: type => alert(type),
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-dynamic-component1',
  template: 'Dynamic Component 1',
})
class MyDynamicComponent1 {
  @Input()
  hello: string;
  @Input()
  something: Function;
  @Output()
  onSomething = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

You have to build an object that has callbacks, values, bindings etc. correlating to the component, and pass it with the dynamic component.

But you should not forget, that such dynamic components are sometimes hard to debug and cause some maintainability issues if you are not carefull enough.

Comment: Thank you! In which step I can bind data for concrete `childComponent` for example by data from event `Subject()`?

Comment: @AlexandraBalmush I edited my answer to privide a example for dynamic input/output data with the correlating component